# Magento store home page

Tags: jquery, html, magento, cookies

I have a popup line which I would like to integrate to the home page. Where should be edited the template files to make this line working properly. The top line(cookies) should push down the entire home page contents until someone click on close. After clicked on close link the home page should return to the top positions. This is my website : http://www.thebodyshop.ie/

and here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

this is the html:

```
<nav id="cookies-popup" style="background-color: #666665; width:100%; height:auto;"><div id="CCompliance" style="display: block; min-width: 751px;background-color: #666665;color: #FFFFFF;font: 13px/13px gill-ss-std,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;padding: 0;margin: 0 auto;z-index: 5;text-align: center;">We use cookies. For more information on our cookie policy<a id="CComplianceLink" href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;font: 13px/40px gill-ss-std,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF;">follow this link.</a>By closing this message or continuing to browse the site, you are agreeing to our use of cookies on this device.<span id="CComplianceClose" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointerfont: 13px/40px gill-ss-std,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF;" onclick="toggle_visibility('CCompliance');">Close</span></div></nav>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very helpful magento extension which is did the job. Very easy to use, and free. Working 100% thanks for the developer Valdecode. If you need something similar to be solved then I strongly recommending to use this extension: EU Cookie Law Compliance, click on the link below.

[EU Cookie Law Compliance](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/eu-cookie-law-compliance-3.html)